# c# how to detect multiple space in file

Tags: c#, .net, file, space, .net-3.0

I want to ignore a line which is either empty , null or just have space or spaces (white spaces).the keyword here is multiple space. I have tried below codes without success

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line1))
```

or

```
if (line2 != "")
```

and I dont want to trim the file because I want to capture
space space abc space space but not space space space space etc
thanks

Comment: I would like to point out that you can't get null by reading a line of text from the file (you might get null for the LAST line using some reading mechanisms though).

Comment: I added the .net-3.0 for the tags list. We can't know what .net version you're using without saying it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**.NET Framework 4:**

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
```

`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is a convenience method that is similar to the
 following code, except that it offers **superior performance**:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;
```

`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` on [MSDN](http://string.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

**.NET Framework < 4:**

you can use that line or:

```
if (value != null && value.Trim().Length > 0)
{...}
```

`Trim` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Comment: is it only in .NET 4? I have to use .NET3. any alternative for me?

Comment: @JohnRyann. Yes that line `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;` ... =)

Comment: This only exists in the .NET 4.0 Framework and future revisions.  Its not clear if he can even use this.  The simple solution of course is to use the String.Compare function and Compare it to the whitespace characters.  An extension method if he isn't using .NET 4.0 would be a valid solution.

Comment: You could also simplify slightly to `value == null || value.Trim().Length == 0`

Comment: awesome. this works : if (value != null && value.Trim().Length > 0)

Comment: @JohnRyann. Why won't it... **:-)** I'm glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

So it can detect if there are only spaces in the string.